# Ruby error, can't start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error when I run `rails s`.

Can anyone help me?

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that
>   /Users/delejnr/Desktop/ruby_playground/observe/log/development.log
>   exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and
>   the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed. Exiting
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:345:in
>   `delete': Permission denied -
>   /Users/delejnr/Desktop/ruby_playground/observe/tmp/pids/server.pid
>   (Errno::EACCES)   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:345:in`
>   check_pid!'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:246:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in`
>   start'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in`
>   tap'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:4:in`require'   from bin/rails:4:in
>   `'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have permission for that file(s).

Start as admin / sudo and check the file permissions and adjust them accordingly.

Also make sure that file( `/Users/delejnr/Desktop/ruby_playground/observe/log/development.log` ) even exists.

Comment: can you please take look at my latest question u seem expert in rails.

Comment: Thanks alot, it exist but how do i check the file permissions?

Comment: @DeleJnrEribo what operating system are you running?

Comment: Ohh i know what you mean, I thought it was something different from that. Thanx a whole lot, i really appreciate it. How long have you coded in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error and ran the following command to fix the permissions:

```
 sudo chmod 0664 <path to app>/<name of app>/log/development.log
```

Replace <path to app> and <name of app>

in your case

```
sudo chmod 0664 /Users/delejnr/Desktop/ruby_playground/observe/log/development.log
```

For Mac 10.11.5